# Wicket Select2 on change listener

Tags: jquery-select2, wicket, onchange

do someone know, how to add onChange behaiviour to Select2 component. I have Select2 component like this :
`Select2Choice select2Choice = new Select2Choice("select2");`

Can someone give me a point how to do this?

Comment: And how to set values to Select2 choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for JavaScript `change` event:

```
select2Choice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             // select2Choice.getModelObject() gives you the selected choice
             // target.add(...); to update some other component
        }
    });
```